# Скрипт бекапа баз данных

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день.

Недавно написал скрипт бекапа баз данных для своего сервера. Некоторое время он не работал из-за настроек сервера, но теперь заработал, но появилась другая проблема.
Помогите ее решить.

Проблема в том, что бекап создается с ломаной кодировкой. Все русские символы становятся нечитабельными. Подскажите, что нужно добавить в код, чтобы исправить эту проблему?

Вот код:

```
$dblocation = "localhost";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpasswd = "12345";

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dblocation,$dbuser,$dbpasswd);

$user_mysql = 'admin';
$pass_mysql = '12345';

$tmp_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/damp/';

function get_database_tables()
{
    $ret = array();
    $r = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES');
    if (mysql_num_rows($r)>0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_NUM))
        {
            $ret[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

$h=array();
$h=get_database_tables();
$vsego=count($h);

$exс=array('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'phpmyadmin');

for ($x=0; $x < $vsego; $x++){
    $bd=$h[$x];
    #И сделаем их дамп
    if(!in_array($bd, $exс)){

        exec('mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' '.$bd.' > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql');
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($h);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: >> Все русские символы становятся не читабельными

Где они нечитабельные? Вы открываете файл в каком-то редакторе и не можете прочитать русский текст?

Или вы выполняете импорт полученного файла и ваш код возвращает ерунду (хотя на основных данных все нормально)? Или после импорта вы через клиент mysql делаете выборку и там ерунда вместо русского текста?

Comment: Я открываю файл в редакторе нодпад++ Бекапы, сделанные через PhpMyadmin в этом же редакторе, открываются отлично

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exec('mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' '.$bd.' > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql');
```

Заменить на

```
exec('mysqldump -u '.$user_mysql.' -p'.$pass_mysql.' '.$bd.' --default-character-set=utf8 > ' . $tmp_path . $bd . '.sql');
```

Comment: Дамп делается через `mysqldump`, а он с `set names` никак не связан ))

Comment: @BOPOH, точно :) Щас исправлюсь)

Comment: насколько я понял это решение будет для баз данных с кодировкой UTF-8 А для кодировки Windows-1251 ?? И есть ли метот сделать определение автоматически и сохранение в нужной кодировке ??

Comment: @alexsis20102, скорее всего, вы боретесь с ветряными мельницами. Сделайте импорт вашего дампа - данные, скорее всего, вставятся нормально. А с n++ проблема в кодировке, попробуйте ее сменить - должно помочь (можно попытаться перед сменой кодировки скопировать текст, а после смены вставить скопированное).

У меня ни разу не было проблем при экспорте дампа с локализацией. При этом никаких дополнительных флагов не указывал. Но я не просматривал дамп в npp, да это чаще всего и не требуется.

Comment: Нет тут явно проблема с кодировкой. Все о чем вы пишете я пробовал. Но зная серверы АГАВЫ тут ничего удивительного. ПОка ищю способы решения вопроса на своей стороне.